# This site can’t be reached - XAMPP ignores custom domain vhosts

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts, hosts

### Environment

- XAMPP 7.2.4 installed on Windows 10
- Apache running on ports 80 and 443

[image]

### Configuration

**`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`**:

```
127.0.0.1 www.test.local test.local
```

**`C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`**:

```
DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs"
<Directory "D:/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**`C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot D:/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "D:/htdocs">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot D:/htdocs
    ServerName test.local
    <Directory "D:/htdocs">
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### The problem

When I start Apache and I access to `localhost` is all right. The problem comes when I try to reach `test.local`: the browser returns a *This site can’t be reached* message. It's like XAMPP ignores the custom domain vhosts defined into `httpd-vhost.conf` file. The same message is displayed with the server off.

```
This site can’t be reached 
The webpage at http://test.local/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

[image]

A few days ago the setup was working and the only changes that I made was the new software installation. I mean, no changes in Apache config files.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other line above containing `test.local`? Try `ping test.local`.

Comment: The `ping` returns a response from `127.0.0.1` and there are not repeated lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your stack were working correctly before, don't be like me and **don't forget to check if some browser extension is blocking your local traffic**, like some extension related with an antivirus system.

In my case it was the Kaspersky Protection extension. When something goes wrong, it shows the following graphic.

[image]

Comment: Haha silly me, thanks man you saved me, I was suddenly facing this weird issue and I was clueless and I forgot that I enable VPN for some reason and after that when I tried to access my local domain it can't and after searching couple of minute found your solution and it's worked for me :)

thanks again

Answer (score 1):

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1   test.local
```

C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/test"
    ServerName test.local
    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/hydroboost/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file with a mapping like this this?

- add this line to the end of the `hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 test.local
```

- the `localhost` domain works without this mapping, because the OS already recognizes "localhost" as a built in alias for the loopback IP address

(this suggestion is assuming that you are running and testing on the same local machine)

Comment: The hosts file is ok. These days I'm realizing it's probably an antivirus problem...